# Spring Jpa with PostgreSql ddl-auto=update is raising error

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

I am creating a security service using spring JPA annotation based. 
in the datasource configuration of `application.properties` I have following configurations

`spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto= update`.

I am getting the following errors

```
objc[22745]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java (0x10c8dc4c0) and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib (0x10c9a44e0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
HOTSWAP AGENT: 15:32:22.999 INFO (org.hotswap.agent.HotswapAgent) - Loading Hotswap agent {1.1.0-SNAPSHOT} - unlimited runtime class redefinition.
HOTSWAP AGENT: 15:32:23.616 INFO (org.hotswap.agent.config.PluginRegistry) - Plugin 'org.hotswap.agent.plugin.hotswapper.HotswapperPlugin' initialized in ClassLoader 'sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2'.
HOTSWAP AGENT: 15:32:23.757 INFO (org.hotswap.agent.config.PluginRegistry) - Discovered plugins: [Hotswapper, WatchResources, AnonymousClassPatch, ClassInitPlugin, Hibernate, Hibernate3JPA, Hibernate3, Spring, Jersey1, Jersey2, Jetty, Tomcat, ZK, Logback, Log4j2, MyFaces, Mojarra, Seam, ELResolver, WildFlyELResolver, OsgiEquinox, Owb, Proxy, WebObjects, Weld, JBossModules, ResteasyRegistry, Deltaspike, JavaBeans, GlassFish]

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.5.9.RELEASE)

HOTSWAP AGENT: 15:32:24.543 INFO (org.hotswap.agent.config.PluginRegistry) - Plugin 'org.hotswap.agent.plugin.spring.SpringPlugin' initialized in ClassLoader 'sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2'.
HOTSWAP AGENT: 15:32:24.544 INFO (org.hotswap.agent.plugin.spring.SpringPlugin) - Spring plugin initialized - Spring core version '4.3.13.RELEASE'
2018-01-07 15:32:24.598  INFO 22745 --- [           main] .s.SpringSecurityWithDatabaseApplication : Starting SpringSecurityWithDatabaseApplication on C02V7092HTD6 with PID 22745 (/Users/yvxm035/personal-workspace/SpringSecurityWithDatabase/target/classes started by yvxm035 in /Users/yvxm035/personal-workspace/SpringSecurityWithDatabase)
2018-01-07 15:32:24.600  INFO 22745 --- [           main] .s.SpringSecurityWithDatabaseApplication : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-01-07 15:32:24.642  INFO 22745 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@c86b9e3: startup date [Sun Jan 07 15:32:24 CST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
HOTSWAP AGENT: 15:32:24.759 INFO (org.hotswap.agent.plugin.spring.SpringPlugin) - Registering basePackage com.security.services
HOTSWAP AGENT: 15:32:25.268 INFO (org.hotswap.agent.config.PluginRegistry) - Plugin 'org.hotswap.agent.plugin.hotswapper.HotswapperPlugin' initialized in ClassLoader 'javax.management.remote.rmi.NoCallStackClassLoader@2f943d71'.
HOTSWAP AGENT: 15:32:25.318 INFO (org.hotswap.agent.config.PluginRegistry) - Plugin 'org.hotswap.agent.plugin.hotswapper.HotswapperPlugin' initialized in ClassLoader 'javax.management.remote.rmi.NoCallStackClassLoader@3dfc5fb8'.
HOTSWAP AGENT: 15:32:25.923 INFO (org.hotswap.agent.config.PluginRegistry) - Plugin 'org.hotswap.agent.plugin.hibernate.HibernatePlugin' initialized in ClassLoader 'sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2'.
2018-01-07 15:32:26.249  INFO 22745 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8084 (http)
2018-01-07 15:32:26.260  INFO 22745 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2018-01-07 15:32:26.261  INFO 22745 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.23
HOTSWAP AGENT: 15:32:26.396 INFO (org.hotswap.agent.config.PluginRegistry) - Plugin 'org.hotswap.agent.plugin.hotswapper.HotswapperPlugin' initialized in ClassLoader 'TomcatEmbeddedWebappClassLoader
  context: ROOT
  delegate: true
----------> Parent Classloader:
sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2
'.
HOTSWAP AGENT: 15:32:26.396 INFO (org.hotswap.agent.config.PluginRegistry) - Plugin 'org.hotswap.agent.plugin.tomcat.TomcatPlugin' initialized in ClassLoader 'TomcatEmbeddedWebappClassLoader
  context: ROOT
  delegate: true
----------> Parent Classloader:
sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2
'.
HOTSWAP AGENT: 15:32:26.397 INFO (org.hotswap.agent.plugin.tomcat.TomcatPlugin) - Tomcat plugin initialized - Tomcat version '8.5.23.0'
2018-01-07 15:32:26.415  INFO 22745 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2018-01-07 15:32:26.416  INFO 22745 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1777 ms
2018-01-07 15:32:26.603  INFO 22745 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2018-01-07 15:32:26.608  INFO 22745 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2018-01-07 15:32:26.608  INFO 22745 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2018-01-07 15:32:26.608  INFO 22745 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2018-01-07 15:32:26.608  INFO 22745 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2018-01-07 15:32:27.177  INFO 22745 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2018-01-07 15:32:27.191  INFO 22745 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2018-01-07 15:32:27.345  INFO 22745 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.0.12.Final}
2018-01-07 15:32:27.346  INFO 22745 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2018-01-07 15:32:27.348  INFO 22745 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2018-01-07 15:32:27.403  INFO 22745 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
2018-01-07 15:32:27.550  INFO 22745 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
2018-01-07 15:32:27.791  INFO 22745 --- [           main] o.h.e.j.e.i.LobCreatorBuilderImpl        : HHH000424: Disabling contextual LOB creation as createClob() method threw error : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
2018-01-07 15:32:27.792  INFO 22745 --- [           main] org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry     : HHH000270: Type registration [java.util.UUID] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.UUIDBinaryType@4be0a27d
2018-01-07 15:32:28.273  INFO 22745 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  : HHH000228: Running hbm2ddl schema update
2018-01-07 15:32:28.340  WARN 22745 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42703
2018-01-07 15:32:28.341 ERROR 22745 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: column t1.tgconstrname does not exist
  Position: 113
2018-01-07 15:32:28.344  WARN 22745 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
2018-01-07 15:32:28.347  INFO 22745 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2018-01-07 15:32:28.360  INFO 22745 --- [           main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-01-07 15:32:28.368 ERROR 22745 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1080) ~[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:857) ~[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) ~[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at com.security.services.SpringSecurityWithDatabaseApplication.main(SpringSecurityWithDatabaseApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:954) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:882) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider._createContainerEntityManagerFactorySpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60) ~[spring-orm-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java) ~[spring-orm-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:360) ~[spring-orm-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:382) ~[spring-orm-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:371) ~[spring-orm-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:336) ~[spring-orm-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Error accessing column metadata: users
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:106) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:109) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:95) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.convertSQLException(InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.java:99) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.getForeignKeys(InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.java:679) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.TableInformationImpl.foreignKeys(TableInformationImpl.java:88) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.TableInformationImpl.getForeignKey(TableInformationImpl.java:99) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.findMatchingForeignKey(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:398) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.applyForeignKeys(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:376) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.doMigrationToTargets(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:214) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.doMigration(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:60) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:134) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:101) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:472) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:444) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:879) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column t1.tgconstrname does not exist
  Position: 113
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2198) ~[postgresql-9.3-1102-jdbc41.jar:na]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1927) ~[postgresql-9.3-1102-jdbc41.jar:na]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:255) ~[postgresql-9.3-1102-jdbc41.jar:na]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:561) ~[postgresql-9.3-1102-jdbc41.jar:na]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:405) ~[postgresql-9.3-1102-jdbc41.jar:na]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeQuery(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:285) ~[postgresql-9.3-1102-jdbc41.jar:na]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2DatabaseMetaData.getImportedExportedKeys(AbstractJdbc2DatabaseMetaData.java:3580) ~[postgresql-9.3-1102-jdbc41.jar:na]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2DatabaseMetaData.getImportedKeys(AbstractJdbc2DatabaseMetaData.java:3775) ~[postgresql-9.3-1102-jdbc41.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.getForeignKeys(InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.java:628) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    ... 35 common frames omitted
```

I made sure that I dont have `user` table as it is a keyword in postgres sql.

And it is working fine and creating the schema when I am using 
`spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto= create-drop`.

But I am not using create-drop as the schema and data will be dropped as soon as the application is stopped and restarted which would be not desired in production.

Please help where I am missing it. I can add more details about the schema I am using and Entities I have in the application. Any help or source of information is appreciated.

Do I have to add any special dependencies while using postgres? I have the PostgresSQl driver dependency in the POM.

Comment: can you post the whole log of the startup that I can see what Hibernate is trying to create?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I have added all the logs of my application.

Comment: Can you please turn on SQL logging. logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG

Comment: Added debug and update the logs. What should I look at in the logs which explains the error. I tried to look for the error and what I can find is `t1.tgconstrname` is a trigger in postgres. My pgsql dependency in pom is version : 9.3-1102-jdbc41. If I pnly use create-drop or create it is working else it is not.

Comment: I can't see the DDL statements that Hibernate is issuing. Are you sure you updated the log?

Comment: Yeah I can observe there are no ddl statements but, that is the error which is coming up right after the application startup. The ddl statements are only coming up when I use `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop`. else with  `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto= update` I am getting the above error.                         I am pretty sure I have update with new logs

Comment: I had an issue with the URL of jdbc instead of localhost I added local so when i add create application was coming up but for update, it was failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after multiple trials and searching for the solution. I found `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto= validate` does the trick. Instead of `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto= update`. Now my schema is working in prod and staging without destroying the schema and recreating for start and stop of the application. Any correction or suggestion on the solution is still appreciated.

Comment: I have found the same problem with a project without spring. I have solved upgrading the postegres driver with 9.4+ version.

Answer (score 1):

Faced the same problem.
Check your version of postgresql driver in POM file.

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.4.1212.jre7</version>
   </dependency>
```

This version is working for me.

Comment: Thank you this version (and all greater then 9.4) solved my issue on my project.